# Does mysql trigger increase the number of connections?

Tags: mysql, triggers

We're planning to add a trigger to a table which contains 30million records. Trigger gets executed after insert and update on this table. We think that adding trigger will increase the connection in mysql which may cause any slowness in the application. Please share your thoughts.

table: entries

```
desc entries; \
Field  | Type |  Null | Key \
entryid varchar(37) NO  PRI \
entrytype   varchar(12) YES     
parentid    varchar(37) YES MUL \
entryname   varchar(255)    NO  
createmember    varchar(37) YES \
createtime  varchar(23) YES \
modifymember    varchar(37) YES \
modifytime  varchar(23) YES \
alive   tinyint(1)  YES
```

AFTER_INSERT:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`%` TRIGGER `test`.`entries_AFTER_INSERT`
        AFTER INSERT ON `entries` FOR EACH ROW \
BEGIN \
  INSERT INTO notifychange (entryid, entrytype, entryname,
      operation, parentid, modifymember, alive, createdAt) 
  VALUES(NEW.entryid, NEW.entrytype, NEW.entryname, "CREATE",
      NEW.parentid, NEW.createmember, NEW.alive, NEW.createtime); \
END
```

AFTER_UPDATE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`%` TRIGGER `test`.`entries_AFTER_UPDATE`
       AFTER UPDATE ON `entries` FOR EACH ROW \
BEGIN \
SELECT count(entryid) INTO @count FROM notifychange
    WHERE entryid=NEW.entryid; \
IF @count=0 THEN \
    INSERT INTO notifychange (entryid, entrytype, entryname,
        operation, parentid, modifymember, alive, createdAt) 
    VALUES(NEW.entryid, NEW.entrytype, NEW.entryname, "UPDATE"
      , OLD.parentid, NEW.modifymember, NEW.alive,
        NEW.createtime); \
ELSE \
    UPDATE notifychange
        SET operation="UPDATE",
            parentid=NEW.parentid,
            modifymember = NEW.modifymember,
            alive=NEW.alive WHERE entryid=NEW.entryid; \
END IF; \
END
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure and the trigger code so we know what the trigger does

Comment: Triggers run in the scope of the transaction triggering them, so no new connection is required.

Comment: Trigger may increase the number of connections in very special cases. For example when it accesses federated table...

Comment: For performance questions, let's talk with specific `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER` and sample queries in front of us.

Comment: @Shadow - It helps. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Have added the details. Please check.

Comment: @RickJames Have added the details. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Akina - We don't use federated table.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization:  The entire AFTER trigger can be a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement.  That change may double the speed of that trigger.

Those ids and members smell like some kind of hash or UUID.  (I am looking at `VARCHAR(37)`.)  That can be inefficient.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  When the table becomes bigger than the buffer_pool, performance degrades for UUIDs.